# Bypass the Cross Domain Issue

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile

Im creating a ios apps using Html,css and Jquery Mobile framework and connecting it to a SOAP xml web service. Since my web service is on the other Pc, I have cross domain issue, but already connected the apps to soap web service but not getting the return (xml format) because of cross domain issue.

My question is ,Is there any way how to bypass the issue? to allow get the return ?
or How to convert the XML return to Json to be acceptable and get the return using jquery Ajax in Html. Thank you for those who will help me.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to install a proxy on your web pc that accesses SOAP and then transparently transmits it. Then you app thinks it comes from the same server and you don't have cross domain problem anymore.

---

Edit : (I would post a comment but the formatting is not the same)

That's exactly the point, you still use `$.ajax` but you send the request to your web server, the server transmits the requests, gets the response and transmits the response back to the client :

```
         request                         request
client ----------->        proxy       ----------> web service
(HTML) <----------- (your web server)  <---------- (anywhere)
         response                        response
```

**Important** : be careful with the way the web service identifies the client, as it will see the requests coming from the same IP (your web server)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) is a good example of a simple PHP proxy that will allow you to return XML.

The key point is that it HAS to be done on either your server, or via a service such as [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/). There is no secret-squirrel way that allows you to do it client-side.

---

So for example, your AJAX call becomes:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=http://remote.server/service.name',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        //Show a loading image here
    },
    success: function(json) {
        //process data here
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //Show an error message here
    }
});
```

Comment: Well you say you're using jQuery Mobile, and presumably using `$.get` or `$.ajax` to query your web service. The point is that you HAVE to point your $.ajax call to the proxy on the same server as your HTML, and that proxy then goes off and queries the web service. The proxy I linked above is nice and simple, and takes a `?url=http://other.server/service` argument.